# Why is casting `&mut &mut i32` as `*mut *mut i32` invalid

Tags: rust, reference, unsafe

I can cast &mut i32 to *mut i32 in rust like so

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;
    let mut xref = &mut x;
    unsafe {
        let xref_ptr = xref as *mut i32;
        *xref_ptr = 2;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Prints 2.

But I can't cast &mut &mut i32 to *mut *mut i32 and I don't understand why.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;
    let mut xref = &mut x;
    let mut xrefref = &mut xref;
    unsafe {
        let xrefptr = xrefref as *mut (*mut i32);
        **xrefptr = 2;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

```
error[E0606]: casting `&mut &mut i32` as `*mut *mut i32` is invalid
  --> src/main.rs:16:23
   |
16 |         let xrefptr = xrefref as *mut (*mut i32);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If references are pointers under the hood I was expecting &mut &mut i32 to be a pointer to pointer to an i32 but it appears this cast is wrong.

Why is the first cast allowed but not the second?

Comment: You can do it in two steps `let xrefptr = (xrefref as *mut &mut i32) as *mut *mut i32;`

Comment: Casts like this generally can only change a single attribute. For instance, you can cast a reference into a pointer, or change the type of the pointer, but not both at once.

Comment: Thank you, @isaactfa I am able to complete the cast in two steps. Feel free to post an example and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @PitaJ points out, you're generally only allowed to do one cast at a time and casts aren't transitive. I.e. `T as U` being valid and `U as V` being valid doesn't imply that `T as V` is valid.

But you can just do the cast in two steps (in safe code!):

```
let mut x = 1;
let mut xref = &mut x;
let mut xrefref = &mut xref;
let xrefptr = (xrefref as *mut &mut i32) as *mut *mut i32;
unsafe {
    **xrefptr = 2;
}
println!("{}", x); // 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The Rust reference has [a list of all possible casting operations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions). In this list, the following ones are relevant for this question in particular:

| Type of `e` | `U` | Cast performed by `e as U` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `*T` | `*V` where `V: Sized` | Pointer to pointer cast |
| `&m₁ T` | `*m₂ T` | Reference to pointer cast (only when `m₁` is `mut` or `m₂` is `const`) |

From this list, we see that we can *either* cast `&mut T` to `*mut T`, *or* we can cast `*mut T` to `*mut V`, but there's no rule that let's us cast from `&mut T` to `*mut V` if `T != V`.

Instead, you can cast in two steps by combining these two rules:

```rust
let xrefref: &mut &mut i32 = &mut xref;
let xref_ptr  = xrefref as *mut &mut i32 as *mut *mut i32;
// &mut T -> *mut T     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// *mut T -> *mut V                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// where T = &mut i32 and V = *mut i32
```

Comment: Thanks is it fair to say this limitation is just to simplify the compiler? So they can avoid trying to find a valid set of transitions from type A to B and just check single changes at a time?

Comment: I suspect it's an intentional language design choice. Going from `&mut T` to `*mut T` is always fine, but going from `*mut T` to `*mut U` is only fine if the types are compatible, otherwise dereferencing the pointer would yield undefined behavior. So I suspect that avoiding the shortcut of `&mut T` to `*mut V` was an intentional choice to avoid accidentally changing the type when going from a reference to a raw pointer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the only reason why it's fine to go from `*mut &mut T` to `*mut *mut T` is because [pointers and references have the same memory layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#pointers-and-references-layout). The compiler doesn't check this, though, and trusts that you know what you're doing, so it'll happly let you convert pointers of any type to any other pointer regardless of whether that's sound or not.